# Using VB.Net, transfer an entire table back into an Oracle Database using a RefCursor with ParamaterDirecion.Input

Tags: vb.net, oracle, plsql

I'm writing a program that is designed to fetch a designated amount of rows from one database and transfer it to another, however, I've run into a bit of a hiccup. I have two database which I am successfully able to connect to, but when it comes to the actual transfer I'm having a problem. At first bulk-copy was the preferred method, but I found out that wasn't quite an option because of another license we would have to acquire. Now as for the important part, I wish to insert the table into the second database using a ref-cursor, but as I know that they can have a direction designated to input, I can't seem to find any hard examples as to how to do it.

```
Public Function Duplicate_Table(ByVal Dest_Conn_String As String, ByVal Source_Conn_String As String,
                                ByVal sqlQuery As String, ByVal table_name As String) As Boolean
    Dim wasDuped As Boolean = False
    Dim source_cmd As New OracleCommand()
    Dim dest_cmd As New OracleCommand()
    Dim tbl As New DataTable
    Dim DA As New OracleDataAdapter

    Try
        With source_cmd
            .Connection = Get_Connected(Source_Conn_String)
            .CommandText = sqlQuery
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .Parameters.Add("o_cursor", OracleType.Cursor)
            .Parameters("o_cursor").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        End With
        DA.SelectCommand = source_cmd
        DA.Fill(tbl)

        With dest_cmd
            .Connection = Get_Connected(Dest_Conn_String)
        'I'm a little unsure as to the query syntax as well, again I've 
        'worked with output cursors but never input
            .CommandText = "Insert Into DEST_TABLE Select * From 
                                refcur_Source;"
            .Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("refcur_Source",         
                 Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.RefCursor,
                               ParameterDirection.Input))
        End With

        'send tbl

        Catch ex As Exception
          Throw ex
        Finally
          Close_Connection(source_cmd.Connection)
          Close_Connection(dest_cmd.Connection)
          DA.Dispose()
        End Try


        Return wasDuped
End Function
```

Any help would be appreciated, or a way to do this without having to use a temp table as a middle man in order to expedite things would be appreciated as well. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is there an over-riding need to use VB.NET? Such as complex business logic? If not then typically I would normally just create a DB link between the two databases and do a select/insert into across the DB link. If you need more logic in the transaction write a stored procedure.

Comment: @PaulStearns Unfortunately yes, database links were looked upon in the beginning but were chosen to be avoided due to the hoops that would have to be jumped through, and other reasons that I just don't recollect.